# Go using error with errorf and not sprintf

Tags: go, formatting, lint

Im using `gometalinter` on my project and for this code

`errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("%s cmd.Std error: %s ", cp[1:], err))`

im getting error `should replace errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(...)) with fmt.Errorf(...) (golint)`

Any idea how to resolve this ?

I try with `errors.New(fmt.Errorf("%s cmd.Std error: %s ", cp[1:], err))` and I got error cannot use fmtErrorf as type string

Comment: No need for errors.New, just fmt.Errorf. e.g. `return fmt.Errorf("%s cmd.Std error: %s ", cp[1:], err)`. fmt.Errorf returns an `error`, errors.New takes a `string` that's why your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @mkopriva - im using package `"github.com/pkg/errors"` , how should I change it? can you provide it as answer ?

Comment: In that case use https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors#Errorf.

Comment: @mkopriva - please provide it as answer and I close the question :) thank you

Comment: The error tells you *exactly* what to do, and it's perfectly clear. What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fmt.Errorf` returns an `error` while `errors.New` takes a `string` that's why your code doesn't compile.

You can simply omit the `errors.New` call or, since you're using the `github.com/pkg/errors` package, you can use https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors#Errorf.